# I’m trying to add a sns service in a step function. And that sns service is having filter policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, publish-subscribe, aws-step-functions

I’ve already created a sns topic and sqs queues with filter policies set. Now I wanted to use this in step function.
So how can I use ?
I know we have to write message attributes in which filter policies were applied but I don’t know how to  specify that in Amazon state language.?
Thanks for help.
As I’m new to Aws so don’t know much about this, so I’m learning.

I tried this-

{
"Type": "Task",
"Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sns:publish",
"Parameters": {
"TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:111122223333:MySNSTopic",
"Message": "{"transaction_no": "12345", "message_body": "This is a test message."}",
"Subject": "Test Message"
},
"Next": "NextState"
}
But this is not correct.
I wanted to send only those message to sqs which are having filter policy of transaction_no

Message": "{"transaction_no": "12345", "message_body": "This is a test message."}",
Is this correct way how we specify filter policies in Amazon state language?